# Rtrtr.com email address

Tags: php, web-applications

I'm new to web developer. a few days ago, rtrt.com email address register with my website. Does it from hacker? this email we should protect? and are there any other email should we avoid for security purpose?

Comment: can you please re-phrase your question ? Also, AFAIK , this has to be decided by you , as to what domains are you permitting in your app

Answer (score 1):

Rtrtr.com just provides disposable Email addresses - they did not want to sign up using their actual Email address so they used a temporary one...

People do this to bypass the "click here to confirm your account" registration steps without providing you their actual Email address. If you want to prevent people from using disposable Email addresses, then yes, you would need to block this domain and many others!